# How to generate a folder on the backend (node) and send it to the client (react)?

Tags: node.js, backend

Im trying to generate a folder on the backend. This folder would contain typescript and tsx code.
Whats the best way to achieve this. Is it possible to use npx commands programmatically in node to generate said folder?

Comment: You can create folders on your backend, but you cannot create folders on the frontend.

Comment: What do you mean by "send it to the client"?

Comment: I mean letting the user download the created folder

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.